# Change name of Win Server 2008 computer after CA install

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I am importing an old certificate database into the new CA on a new server I'm installing. I am warned by Windows that I can't change the computer name, domain settings, etc., after installing the CA. However, I may need to change the name or domain settings if they appear incorrect and the certificates that are already installed no longer work. In the event that this happens, I can uninstall the CA roles, delete the new database from the machine, etc., and try again with my copy of the old server's certificates.

Does anyone know how I can ensure that I will be able to do this successfully if necessary? Does Windows just give up the lock if I remove the CA roles?